# Running code with reprex() and from console produces different result

Tags: r, dplyr, lazy-evaluation, rlang

I am trying to understand why my code produces a different result when run with `reprex::reprex()` than directly from the script and how to consistently produce the output of the `reprex()` call. The issue emerges within the `filter()` call.

- **Example 1** shows my function filters the data.frame rows based on a column's matches with another vector when I select, copy, and then run it with `reprex::reprex()` in RStudio.
- **Example 2** (screenshot from the console output) shows that running the exact same code directly in the script throws a `'match' requires vector arguments` error.
- **Example 3** shows with a slight modification of the function that `!!sym()` appears to be creating some sort of time series object. Omitting `sym()` and replace `==` with `%in%` has the same consequence.

**UPDATE:**

The issue did not replicate on others' machines nor my own. I swapped out of an RStudio project to a single .R file and it still persisted. However, when I Cntrl+Shift+F10 to detach libraries, data, etc. the discrepancy vanished. This suggested that I was deal with some sort of namespace issue. Upon returning to the RStudio Project, the issue returned. However, calling `dplyr::filter()` within the function resolved the issue - reinforcing it being a namespace issue.

While the accepted answer provides some solutions and correctly identifies the issue, the outstanding question (for another post) is why the namespace precedence was not applied in this case when I loaded the package immediately beforehand.

#### Example 1: `!!sym()` produces a vector for `%in%` as expected when code is run with `reprex::reprex()`

```r
# Packages
library(dplyr)
library(rlang)

# Example data
mydat <- data.frame(type = c("a","b","c","a","c"))
myvec <- c("a","c")

# Example function
foo <- function(df, type_var = "type", vec){
  df %>% 
    filter(!!sym(type_var) %in% vec)
}

# Call function
foo(df = mydat, type_var = "type", vec = myvec)
#>   type
#> 1    a
#> 2    c
#> 3    a
#> 4    c
```

#### Example 2: Console output shows type error when run from within an R script

[image]

#### Example 3: slightly modified function shows that `!!sym()` is creating a time series object?!

```r
# Example function
foo <- function(df, type_var = "type", vec){
  df %>% 
    filter(!!sym(type_var) == "a")
}

# Apply function
foo(df = mydat, type_var = "type", vec = myvec)

#>Time Series:
#>Start = 1 
#>End = 5 
#>Frequency = 1 
#>     [,1]
#> [1,]    0
#> [2,]    0
#> [3,]    0
#> [4,]    0
#> [5,]    0
```

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue. I get the expected outputs even when running R in the command line.

Comment: Yes, I'm going to guess this is some sort of systems issue or conflict with RStudio. Do you get different output from that observed in Example 3? @phiver

Comment: output in example 3: a data.frame with 2 values of a and a column header type as it should be.

Comment: Going to run another test to see if I can consistently produce the error, but I was able to fix it by cntrl+shift+f10 even after doing rm(list=ls()). Suggests something about objects in memory or packages. If I can reproduce it I'll keep it open and post an answer. Otherwise, I'll delete I guess?

Comment: it's to do with which ``filter`` you're using. Imported from `stats` gives an error whereas from `dplyr` it doesn't.

Comment: I figured out how to reproduce it on my machine and @user438383 is absolutely correct. If I'm in a specific RStudio project, the error happens. If I'm not in the project, it doesn't. However, if I'm *in the project* and also call `dplyr::filter()` then it fixes itself. Sounds like some sort of namespace issue? Or maybe an issue with .rprofile or .renviron  which loads packages? Surprising though that loading `dplyr` just before this doesn't fix this...



I just tested and you're absolutely correct that when I call `dplyr::filter()` it works.

Comment: @socialscientist my guess it's an ``~/.Rprofile`` issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's related to which version of `filter` is being used and whether it's imported from `stats` or `dplyr`. I suspect you have an `~/.Rprofile` somewhere that's loading some library functions which are being loaded sometimes and not others.

Changing example 3 to

```
foo <- function(df, type_var = "type", vec){
  df %>% 
    dplyr::filter(!!sym(type_var) == "a")
}

# Apply function
foo(df = mydat, type_var = "type", vec = myvec)
```

yields:

```
  type
1    a
2    a
```

Similarly changing example 1 to:

```
library(dplyr)
library(rlang)

# Example data
mydat <- data.frame(type = c("a","b","c","a","c"))
myvec <- c("a","c")

# Example function
foo <- function(df, type_var = "type", vec){
  df %>% 
    dplyr::filter(!!sym(type_var) %in% vec)
}

# Call function
foo(df = mydat, type_var = "type", vec = myvec)
```

gives:

```
  type
1    a
2    c
3    a
4    c
```

Beware of namespace collisions when running R in console/Rscript etc, it can be hard to track down bugs. `filter` and `lag` are the chief culprits (source I almost had to retract a journal paper because `lag` was imported from the wrong namespace on an Rscript and failed in a weird and silent way).

Comment: Yeah, I just checked and if I use `dplyr::filter()` it works.  See my comment on my question.  This is strange though...I just loaded `dplyr` at the top of the script and run the entire thing just like with `reprex()`. If I'm not mistaken, this should use `dplyr`'s.   

Issue here is that while I used to call EVERYTHING with `::`, code becomes borderline unreadable. Once again, I think issue has to be with Projects in RStudio.

I'll probably accept this answer, just let me see if there's anything else I can find for how to actually solve it.

Comment: Check out the [conflicted library](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/conflicted/index.html). Or even just do ``filter = dplyr::filter`` at the start of a script.

Comment: The first sentence of that link is exactly why I'm confused about this:  "R's default conflict management system gives the most recently loaded package precedence." `dplyr` was most recently loaded hm.

Will play with this more, but probably has to do with this being in my .rprofile and loading 
`auto_loads <- c("dplyr","tidyr","ggplot2","cmdstanr")
load_quiet <- function(one_package){
  suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(one_package, character.only=TRUE))
}

# Apply the function in interactive mode
if(interactive()){
  invisible(sapply(auto_loads, load_quiet))
}`